# awakeFromNib is not called for UITableViewCell object

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, xcode-storyboard, awakefromnib

I have a class that inherits from `UITableViewCell`, it has a bunch of `IBOutlets`. I had previously been using this object in a way that reuses the cell and initializes it as it's needed. This method is too slow, so I decided to create an array of the `UITableViewCell` objects and then add them as needed in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Everything gets loaded fine except the `IBOutlet` objects. `awakeFromNib` is never called so I assume this has something to do with my issue.

Just to clarify it was getting called fine when I was initializing the cells in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, it's just when I tried to preload them in the view controllers `viewWillAppear` method that it breaks.

Comment: Whatever you're up to I suggest you stop and have a good read through the `UITableView` documentation. "create an array of the UITableViewCell objects and then add them as needed in the cellForRowAtIndexPath: function." really isn't the way to go about things.

Comment: Can you possibly explain why not? My table only has less than 10 objects in it so preloading them up front shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: It's just not the way the `UITableView` is meant to work. I find it a little strange that the regular way of using the table view is too slow. I suggest that you use a profiler to find what's really taking up time.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Comment: I'm sorry but linking to a a page that says how to create a UITableView isn't exactly helpful. As I said in the post I have successfully created one the standard way (as laid out in that link) and it works fine. What I'm trying to do now is preload them, why is that a bad thing? The only thing it's not currently doing is linking to the nib file, everything else works fine it's laid out correctly and it scrolls fine and I can select the individual cells. Just none of the buttons or labels that I defined in the storyboard.

Comment: I have profiled using instruments, the reason it's so slow is that it's creating a new cell every time it goes on and off screen. The cell contains images and labels and buttons. If it's possible the simplest solution would be to not create a new cell every time it goes off screen and cache them instead, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am not saying that you are wrong and that it's not a bad thing. I would just like to know why?

Comment: In your comment above, you say it's not linking to the nib file, but then you say you defined the subviews in a storyboard. Where did you make this cell, nib or storyboard? Where do you images come from -- are they local,  or are you downloading them from somewhere?

Comment: Sorry the nib and storyboard were the same thing. I create the table view and cell in the storyboard. The images are all local.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question. But after reading the conversation, I feel I must give some input. This a multi-layered issue that you are dealing with here.

Firstly, when you say "preload" what is it that you mean exactly.? Are you calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in your `viewWillAppear`? Or are you calling an `init`. Either way this is not an acceptable practice whatsoever.

Remember, the UITableViewCells are "Reusable" meaning that the UITableView, in effect, handles the unloading and loading of the `UITableViewCells` when they are offscreen to optimize performance (not memory, believe it or not) as well as some other things. Essentially, it's a pretty nifty "hack" to keep table views efficient. So if your `UITableView` is too slow, then you are doing something wrong, not the implementation of `UITableView`

When you say you are "preloading" them, that throws up some immediate red flags on your usage. And when you say "the method is too slow", well it's not. The delegate/datasource methods in place for UITableViews and UICollectionViews happen in calculated orders. Don't fight it.

Secondly, for your issue with `awakeFromNib` not getting called. You aren't providing enough information. How did you initialize it? If you created it in your storyboard/nib, you shouldn't be calling any of the `init` methods. In fact, as of iOS6 you are guaranteed a non-nil cell from `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Answer (score -1):

Have you called it through its super class like :

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib]; // Use this line 
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have it called just like that. It works when it's loaded on the fly but doesn't get called when I try to preload it and store it in an array.